# hey ,i have created a program in gui tkinter in python and couldnt upload image as label/icon eventhough they are under same project

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
icon = PhotoImage(file="X.png")
window.iconphoto(True,icon)

window.mainloop()
#my code
```

#error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\priya\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    icon = PhotoImage(file="X.png")
  File "C:\Users\priya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\priya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4038, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "X.png"
```

Comment: The error suggests that `X.png` is not a valid PNG. Did you check if this file is really a PNG and displays correctly in an image viewer?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the file `X.png` is not a valid PNG image file, try viewing it in a image viewer and check its filetype via https://www.checkfiletype.com/ or using the `file` command via WSL.